# Upgrade apache to next version

Tags: apache-2.2

I have task to upgrade some software on windows server using remote desctop connection. One of it is apache web server. I never do that before.When I try to install new version, it asks to remove current. It means I will loose all configurations. Is it possible to upgrade apache 2.2 to 2.2.x version without loss any configurations?

Comment: How did this work out? I'm about to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

most of the configuration files will probably work within a point release (2.2.2 > 2.2.8) ect.

Really all you can do is back it up & try it.

Or, install the new version, and modify the configuration that has changed.